# Property or method "registerUser" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: templates, methods, vue.js, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

index.blade.php

```
<div id="register">
    ...
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="registerUser">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

manage.js

```
var DomainUsers = {
    template: `...`,
    data: function(){
        return { domainUserData }
    }
}

var mainview = new Vue({
    el: "#mainview",
    components: {
        'domain-users': DomainUsers
    },
    data: {},
    method: {
        registerUser: function () { console.log('test') }
    }
})
```

[Vue warn]: Property or method "registerUser" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
(found in root instance)

[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "click": got undefined 
(found in root instance)

How should I fix code for using @click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your manage.js, you've named it `method` instead of `methods` (plural), so Vue can't find it. That should fix it:

```
var mainview = new Vue({
    // ....

    // plural:
    methods: {
        registerUser: function () { console.log('test') }
    }
})
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods for more details.